# Simple compact special unitary Lie group and dicyclic group Dic$_{k}$=Q$_{4k}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, lie-groups

Given a simple compact Lie group, SU($n$) group, for $n=2,3,4,...$,

Can we determine what are the **allowed [dicyclic group Dic$_{k}$ (=generalized quaternion groups Q$_{4k}$ (of order $k=2,4,8,...$)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dicyclic_group) realized as a subgroup embedded into SU($n$)?**

What is the restriction of $k$ for given  SU($n$) of

$n=2?$

$n=3?$

$n=4?$

$n=5?$

(BONUS but not necessary: Are there some general rules one can use to determine any $n$ what is the allowed $k$?)

Comment: Character tables?